# How to set the SQL Database Project in the Visual Studio 2017 connected to the Database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, github

I am working on SQL Database Project in the Visual Studio 2017. Purpose is to push only the Stored Procedure Changes to VSTS Git.

Instead of connecting to the Database from the Project Solution, I am using Import SQL Scripts.

In this approach, any changes in the stored procedure has to be copied and pasted on the stored procedure in the Project Solution.

How to set the SQL Database Project in the Visual Studio 2017 connected to the Database? And Connecting to the Database should not allow Import option to extract the all other database objects such as Table, View from SQL to Visual Studio. We do not want all other scripts. We just need only those Stored Procedures to be sync with database environment.

At present, we are making the changes to the Stored Procedures in the SQL Management Studio. Further then, we manually copy the SQL Script from SQL Management Studio to Visual Studio Environment.

Whether, will it be possible for us to have the changes auto-sync between SQL Management Studio to Visual Studio (or) by refreshing the Visual Studio Project.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a stored procedure in a local environment, adding it to the DB project, then pushing to a development environment? If so, that's somewhat involved, but you can basically accomplish this with Schema Compare and your Release definition.

Comment: Either Create or Update Stored Procedure, we are using SQL Management Studio. To push the code to Git, we are copying from SQL  Studio to Visual Studio. I prefer to have a sync connection between Visual Studio and the Database. At the same time, Sync connection should be limited to selected Stored Procedures and not bringing all Tables, Views, etc.. because we have over 1000 of tables

Comment: I think I know what you're trying to do now. I'll leave an answer below. Please let me know if I'm off base.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> SQL Server -> Schema Compare. At the top of the new window, access the dropdown, and put your local DB connection (where you've added the stored procedure) on the left, and your DB project on the right. Hit Compare, and then Update. This should update the dbo directory in your Database project to match the local db schema, whether you're adding 1 proc or 100.

At this point, you'll also need to add a reference to the stored procedure to your database project in VS. Put the .sqlproj into a text editor, add the reference (there will be lots of examples to copy; it should be easy), save, and build the project to make sure you got it right. git add, commit, and push!

This only works if the schema of your local DB matches what is in the VS project. If you want to copy something from a database with a different schema, I *think* you're stuck copy-pasting.

AFAIK, there is no way to automate this, but I would love to be corrected about that. It would save me so much time at work. :)